# Como definir a codificação padrão UTF-8 de páginas no IIS do Windows Server?

Tags: html, asp, bootstrap-3, iis-7, codificação-de-conteúdo

Tenho um problema de codificação (acentuação) com os *template* padrão do `Bootstrap`, especificamente o `carousel`.

O código oficial possuí os meta definidos assim:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta content="charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico"> (...)
```

Porém quando coloco palavras como: *Início*, *Observações*, ou qualquer outra palavra com acentuação, mesmo com o `charset` definido como `utf-8` a página apresenta uma interrogação em losango.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade pessoal, já consegui resolver. O problema é que por o `Bootstrap` estar relacionado ao `HTML`, `CSS` e Javascript. Não definimos para template o tipo da página que se aplicará aquela codificação.

Por exemplo, a página que eu estava usando recuperava sessões do `ASP`, por isso a acentuação não funcionava, por isso o `ISS` não estava codificando a página com `UTF-8`.

Inseri no código o `content text/asp` e funcionou, o mesmo serve se você irá utilizar os template do `Bootstrap` misturado com páginas de linguagens em servidores `ISS`:

```
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta content="text/asp;  charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico"> (...)
```